# Simple homomorphism of groups question

Tags: group-theory

Show that a homomorphism of groups also has the property that $f(a^{-1})=f(a)^{-1}$ for all $a \in G$.

Comment: Hint: $aa^{-1} = e$

Comment: That's the definition of an inverse. I know that... I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Where does a homomorphism send the identity?

Comment: @Homegrown Tomato:  love your new look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

Start with f(1).

1 = a^-1 * a

f(a^-1 * a) = f(a^-1)*f(a) (because f is a homomorphism)

so, 1 = f(a^-1)*f(a).

Right-multiply by f(a)^-1, so

f(a)^-1 = f(a^-1)*f(a)*f(a)^-1 = f(a^-1)*1 = f(a^-1). Done!