# Prove that for each element $a$ in $G_{1}$, $f(a^{-1})=[f(a)]^{-1}$

Tags: group-isomorphism

Prof. Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra" presents this exercise:

> Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be groups, and let $f: G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ be an isomorphism.
>
> Prove that for each element $a$ in $G_{1}$, $f(a^{-1})=[f(a)]^{-1}$. [Hint - you may use Theorem 2 of Chapter 4.]

This theorem states:

> If $G$ is a group and $a$, $b$ are elements of $G$, then $ab=e$ implies $a=b^{-1}$ and $b=a^{-1}$.

Given that theorem, I'm not sure how to apply it to answer the exercise. Please give me a hint.

Comment: what is $f$....?

Comment: Updated the question*, @passenger.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple homomorphism of groups question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119920/simple-homomorphism-of-groups-question)

Comment: @Dietrich Burde et al:  Recursive duplication!  The question you linked is closed as a duplicate of yet another version, which itself is still open!  My mathemagical funny bone is tingling . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $f:G \to H$ is a homomorphism of groups, note that for any $a \in G$

$e_H =  f(e_G) = f(aa^{-1}) = f(a)f(a^{-1}); \tag{1}$

now by the given theorem, renaming $a, b$ in its statement $f(a)$ and $f(a^{-1})$, respectively, we have

$f(a^{-1}) = [f(a)]^{-1} \tag{2}$

and so forth.  ***QED!***

***Note:***  $f(e_G) = e_H$ since

$f(e_G) = f(e_G^2) = [f(e_G)]^2, \tag{3}$

whence

$e_H = [f(e_G)]^{-1} f(e_G) = [f(e_G)]^{-1}[f(e_G)]^2 = f(e_G). \tag{4}$

***End of Note.***

Answer (score 2):

We have $e_2=f(e_1)=f(aa^{-1})=f(a)f(a^{-1})$, because $f$ is a group homomorphism. Now apply Theorem $2$.

Comment: Could you please explain why $e = f(e)$?

Comment: Because of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309678/prove-f-matches-group-g-1s-neutral-element-in-group-g-2, which you have asked before.

Comment: So using your helpful answer, $e_2=f(a)f(a^{-1})$. Multiply $f(a)^{-1}$ by each side to get: $f(a)^{-1}e_2=f(a)^{-1}f(a)f(a^{-1})$. Remove the neutral element on the left-hand side, and cancel out the first two terms of right-hand side to get: $f(a)^{-1}=f(a^{-1})$. Is that right, @Dietrich?

Comment: You could directly use Theorem $2$. Take $A=f(a)$ and $B=f(a^{-1})$. We have $AB=e$, so that $B=A^{-1}$, i.e. $f(a^{-1})=f(a)^{-1}$.